# Error 0x80041103 (doesn't contain attribute) while using groupby in the Microsoft Dataverse Web API

Tags: dataverse

I am trying to aggregate using "group by" on a lookup field in the Dataverse API.

Example:
`$apply=groupby((<lookupfield>/<fieldname>), aggregate($count as total))`

The error message I'm getting is:

code=0x80041103
{table} entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'ownerid' and NameMapping = 'Platform'.

`{"error":{"code":"0x80041103","message":"'SystemUser' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'ownerid' and NameMapping = 'Platform'. MetadataCacheDetails: ProviderType=Dynamic, StandardCache=True, IsLoadedInStagedContext = False}}`

Here are very simple tests to use in a browser.  (PrimaryContactId and PreferredSystemUserId are both lookup fields in the default accounts table.)

This works:
`<organizationURL>/api/data/v9.2/accounts?$apply=groupby((primarycontactid/fullname))`

This errors:
`<organizationURL>/api/data/v9.2/accounts?$apply=groupby((preferredsystemuserid/fullname))`

It also fails on some tables that have an Owner ID.  The error message is the same, but it mentions the root entities instead of the related entities.

This errors:
`<organizationURL>/api/data/v9.2/cr203_newtables?$apply=groupby((cr203_Lookup/cr203_code))`

`'cr203_newtable' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'cr203_Lookup' and NameMapping = 'Platform'`

(Different error "Property not found" if I use Logical Name instead - cr203_lookup/cr203_code)

Comment: A good workaround is to use ?fetchXML= in the REST Web API.  You can do this grouping using XML, but looks like maybe cannot through standard REST.